# How to find the number of faces of a rhombicosadodecahedron?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I need to use the Euler's formula. I know there are $62$ faces...first, how do I find the number of vertices it has. From there, I can get the amount of edges, which will then in turn get me the number of faces. The question states as follows: A rhombicosadodecahedron is a polyhedron whose every vertex is incident to one triangular, one pentagonal, and two (opposite) quadrilateral faces. Find the number of faces.

Comment: How are the faces shaped?  If you temporarily ignore the polyhedron and instead focus your attention solely on a single specific face, how many vertices are on said face?  How many edges are on said face?  How many faces share a vertex?  How many faces share an edge?  If each face has $v$ vertices touching it, and each vertex is shared by $s$ faces, how much have we overcounted if we did $62v$ having recounted each vertex multiple times once for each face?

Comment: With the update, the same suggestions apply, except you will need to keep track of how many of each type of face there are.  Let there be $T$ triangular faces, let $P$ be the number of pentagonal faces, and let $Q$ be the number of quadrilateral faces.  How many edges per each type of face?  How many vertices per each type of face?  If we know $V-E+F=2$ and we describe each of $V,E,F$ in terms of $P,Q,T$, what information can we glean from this?  Recommend similar technique as found [here for counting number of panels on the soccer ball.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nyo3TjKyu_c).

Comment: There would $3n=2e$ for T and the # of faces is $n/3=f_3$. $(4n=2e)$ and the # of faces is $(n/4)+(n/4)=f_4$ for Q. Then $5n=2e$ for P and # of faces if $n/5=f_5$. Then I add up all for the faces?

Answer (score 1):

Let $v,e,f,p,q,t$ represent the total number of vertices, edges, faces, pentagons, quadrilaterals and triangles in the polyhedron respectively.

We know that $v-e+f=2$ due to the Euler characteristic of the sphere.

We also know $f=p+q+t$

Also $e = \frac{5p+4q+3t}{2}$ as each pentagon contributes five edges, each quadrilateral contributes four edges, etc... The division by two comes from each edge being adjacent to two faces simultaneously

Next, $v = \frac{5p+4q+3t}{4}$ as again each pentagon contributes five vertices, etc... but each vertex is adjacent to a total of four faces.

So, putting this information together, we have $2 = v-e+f = \frac{5p+4q+3t}{4}-(\frac{5p
+4q+3t}{2}) + p+q+t$

Combining fractions, we have:

$8 = 5p+4q+3t-10p-8q-6t+4p+4q+4t = t-p$

So, we know that there must be eight more triangles than there are pentagons.

To reach a final conclusion on the specific number of each type of face, we look at a picture of how each shape interacts:

[image]

We see that from the perspective of the pentagons, there are five neighboring triangles.  So, $5p$ would overcount the number of triangles.  Each triangle however is counted by three pentagons.  So, we have the relation $\frac{5}{3}p = t$.

Similarly, we have $\frac{5}{2}p=q$

Combining this with the information we had before, that $t=p+8$, we have $\frac{5}{3}p=p+8$ and thus $\frac{2}{3}p=8$ and $p=12$.

Then, $t=20$ and $q=30$

There must then be $20$ triangles, $30$ quadrilaterals and $12$ pentagons, making a total of $p+q+t=62$ faces.

We could also go back and find the total number of vertices and edges if we desired now that we have found the number of each type of face.